# Adding drop down divs to content

Tags: entities

I have search and searched and have not found this question yet. Nor have I found a way to do it.

I want to have a page built where it has a few fields, Objectives, Audience, Credits, Location, etc. I want the user to be able to type in all content on one edit screen.

When you view the page I want a horizontal bar with the fields listed - Objectives, Audience, Credits, Location - and when you click on the name Objective, the information for objective pops down in a div. When you click on Audience - text for audience pops down. This would be below the main body copy of the page.

I was thinking maybe fields group or conditional fields for forms however I do not see how those would work.

Does anyone have any ideas? a tutorial to send me too? a module to review?

Thanks
Tim

Comment: Sounds like you are asking about collapsible fieldsets...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could use something like [Field Group](http://dgo.to/field_group) and use Horizontal Tabs, seems like it would work the way you want.

1. Under **Manage Display** of the content type, add a **Horizontal Tabs Group**.
2. Then a **Horizontal Tab Item** for each field or section you want. The label you put in will be what shows up on the tab.
3. Nest the tabs underneath, and then put the fields you want underneath each tab.

The result will should look something like this. With a bit of CSS, you can make it look different.

### Manage Display

[image: Manage Display and Field Group]

### Final Result

[image: Final Result]